# how to assign terminal variable from previous command's output

Tags: macos, terminal

I'm very very new to the terminal script world.  Here's what I want to do:

```
1) Find out the process that's using a given port (8000 in this case)
2) Kill that process
```

Pretty simple.  I can do it manually using:

```
lsof -i tcp:8000 -- get the PID of what's using the port
kill -9 $PID -- terminate the app using the port
```

For reference, here's exactly what gets returned when using lsof -i tcp:8000

```
COMMAND   PID       USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
php     94735     MyUser    5u  IPv6 0x9fbd127eb623aacf      0t0  TCP localhost:irdmi (LISTEN)
```

Here's my problem: **how do I capture the PID value from `lsof -i tcp:8000` so that I can use that variable for the next command?**  I know how to create variable that I assign... just not ones that are dynamically made.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The thing you’re looking for is called [command substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Substitution). It lets you treat the output of a command as input to the shell.

For example:

```
$ mydate="$(date)"
$ echo "${mydate}"
Mon 24 Feb 2014 22:45:24 MST
```

It’s also possible to use `` `backticks` `` instead of the dollar sign and parentheses, but most [shell style guides](https://google.github.io/styleguide/shell.xml#Command_Substitution) recommend avoiding that.

In your case, you probably want to do something like this:

```
$ PID="$(lsof -i tcp:8000 | grep TCP | awk '{print $2}')"
$ kill $PID
```

Comment: Works great and you've linked to a good resource!  Thank You!

Comment: The link has been removed :(

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines should work:

```
lsof -i tcp:8000 | grep TCP | read cmd pid restofline
kill -9 $pid
```

before using the kill command, just echo it to make sure.

Comment: Something like `(read cmd pid restofline && kill -9 $pid)` might be better, so that the `$pid` variable set in the pipe subshell isn’t lost on going to the next command.